# How to make postman works with urls containing a dot between slashes (current dir)

Tags: url, postman

## Problem

Getting a URL that contains `/./` inside from a redirection.

I run a GET `{{base}}/main-menu`. The response is 302 with a redirect to `./menu`

Postman is trying to GET `{{base}}/./main` (with the `./` inside) and fails with a `404`.

But if try that in the navigator I get what I want.

## Question

Is there a setting or a way to make this works in Postman in an authomated way?

(with authomated way I ment to not touching by hand).

## Reproduction steps

Set a GET to https://nodejs.org/./en in Postman fails. In the navigator works.

I'm using Postman 9.31.0

[image: image description here]

Comment: Did you try to use absolute path / full URL for the redirection ? - Based on : https://community.postman.com/t/redirects-for-relative-urls-not-working/21461

Comment: @hidigoudi, Yes, I try it, and works. But I don't want to edit by hand every URL redirect having a `./` from a server that I cannot change. It's a pity that Postman doesn’t do the change that the navigator is doing automatically. Long story short: If I don't have a `/./` I don't have the problem. But, because I get a `./` I still having a problem.